# Necessary conditions for mixed concavity and convexity.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis

The questions is originally physical, but the problem is purely mathematical. We have a function

$$F(T,V,N) = A\left(\frac{N^5 T}{V^3}\right)^{1/2}\quad \text{for}\quad A,N,T,V\in\mathbb{R^+}, A\neq 0$$

which must be convexe w.r.t. $V$ and $N$, but concave w.r.t. $T$. Now we are asked to determine whether this conditions are satisfied by $F$. What is confusing me is the following: the corrector says that no, the conditions aren't satisfied because

$$\partial_N^2F\cdot\partial_V^2F - (\partial_V\partial_NF)^2 = -\frac{675}{16} A^2 N^3 T V^{-5} \leq 0$$

Why is this true? I'm getting no satisfying answer, and looking it up on internet hasn't given me any answer. My questions are, in particular, the following:

1. What are **sufficient** conditions for a function on a $n$-dimensional space to be concave w.r.t. to some variables and convexe w.r.t. to the rest? As far as I understand, if it is concave w.r.t. to $k$ variables, its Hessian matrix should have $k$ negative eigenvalues, and the opposite applies to the remaining $n-k$ variables which is convexe w.r.t. If a general answer can't be given, consider only 3-dimensional domains.
2. What are the **necessary** conditions that must be satisfied by the $2\times 2$ minors of the Hessian matrix of a function as described above (concave and convexe depending on the variable considered). Is the reasoning of my corrector really correct in the case of this exercise?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at concave and convex separately. For (joint) convexity in $V$ and $N$, the Hessian of $F$ w.r.t. $V$ and $N$ needs to be positive semidefinite. You can also look at separate convexity (i.e., the diagonal of the Hessian), but joint convexity is a stronger property and guarantees that a local minimum is globally optimal. Separate convexity is hardly used. I do not have the full context, but it appears to refer to joint convexity.

The derivative of $F$ w.r.t. $V$ and $N$ is:
$$\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{3}{2} A N^{5/2} T^{1/2} V^{-5/2} \\ \frac{5}{2} A N^{3/2} T^{1/2} V^{-3/2} \end{pmatrix}$$
so the Hessian is:
$$\frac{15}{4} A \begin{pmatrix} N^{5/2} T^{1/2} V^{-7/2} & - N^{3/2} T^{1/2} V^{-5/2} \\
- N^{3/2} T^{1/2} V^{-5/2} & N^{1/2} T^{1/2} V^{-3/2} \end{pmatrix}$$

The determinant of the Hessian is $0$ (not $-(675/16) A^2 N^3 T V^{-5}$ as claimed), so the eigenvalues are $0$ and the trace. The trace is also positive (since $A$ is positive), so the function is convex.

As for necessary/sufficient: if the Hessian exists everywhere, a function is convex if and only if the Hessian is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Suppose that, for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}:(x,y,z)\mapsto f(x,y,z)$, we decide to study the $2\times 2$ Hessian matrices obtained by considering each time a variable as fixed. If we suppose $f$ to be jointly convex with all three variables, is it a necessary condition that each of the $2\times 2$ Hessian matrices be positive semi-definite too? This is, for example, if $\partial_x^2f\cdot\partial_y^2f - (\partial_x\partial_y f)^2 \leq 0$, would that necessarily imply that $f$ was not jointly convex with respect to all its variables?

Comment: @Hal yes that condition is necessary. If the $2\times 2$ matrix is not positive semidefinite, then the full Hessian is also not positive semidefinite (this readily follows from the $x^THx \geq 0$ definition of psd)

Comment: Is this true for any $n$-dimensional domain, or only for a function depending on three variables? If $f$ depended on $n$ variables $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ and again we had $\partial_{x_i}^2f\cdot\partial_{x_j}^2f - (\partial_{x_i}\partial_{x_j} f)^2 \leq 0$, for $i \neq j$, would that imply that $f$ could not be jointly convex w.r.t. all its variables? (This is my last question, thank you for your perseverance).

Comment: @Hal did you follow that $x^TH x \geq 0$ argument?

Comment: Trying to explain why I did not get it, I actually got it. Hahaha. Thank you. :)